# What is the difference between linear and non-linear color space system?

Tags: image-processing, colors

What is the difference between linear and non-linear color space systems?

I faced these concepts in computer vision course newly, could any one describe the difference "artlessly" .. ?

Comment: This link seems to explain the difference pretty thoroughly: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LinearLighting.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a linear color space, color mixtures follow the ordinary blending laws. For instance, mixing half of pure red with half of pure blue gives the average color,

```
½ (100%, 0%, 0%) + ½ (0%, 0%, 100%) => (50%, 0%, 50%)
```

In a non-linear color space, such as HLB, this is not true. Here are the corresponding representations:

```
(0°, 100%, 100%), (240°, 100%, 100%), (300°, 100%, 50%)
```

RGB, CMY, YUV, YCrCb, XYZ are linear systems.
HLS, HSB, HSV, HSI, Lab, Luv, Yxz are not.

Some colorimetric spaces are deemed "perceptually uniform", meaning that the percieved difference between two colors is proportional to their numerical distance in the color space. They are not linear.

Comment: Note that sRGB is not a linear color space.